# Angular use service without actual type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular15

I have component, that should do API request. I also have some abstract class for such services. It has constructor as

```
export class ODataService<T> extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, api: string) {
    super(http, null);
    this.servicePath = `odata/${api}`;
  }
}
```

so not empty constructor. I don't want to write separate service only for 1 method for 1 component. So I am thinking about "create one-time use" service using abstract class only for that component. I though something about this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [{
    provide: 'myService',
    useFactory: (http) => new ODataService<IModel>(http, 'endpoint'),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() entityId: string

  constructor(private myService: ODataService<IModel>) {
    super();
  }
}
```

The problem - it seems I cannot create types "on-demand", and injecting service like that in component constructor generates error:

> This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.

So question - is something like that possible?

Comment: Given that Java is already inherently verbose anyway, is this really a good use of your time?

Comment: @RobertHarvey ?

Comment: I am saying that overall it's probably cheaper just to do it the usual way.

Comment: I agree with @RobertHarvey. This isn't worth the time. As an architect of large Angular projects for Labcorp, we use inheritance in our services to consolidate common methods, etc. You can extend classes that leverage generics though, if you're needing to pass in a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this what you're looking for, but you can extend classes that leverage generics to set types.

For example, we have a service that picks up environment values that are set server-side.

```js
// ngx-environment.service.ts


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgxEnvironmentService<T> {

  environment: T;

  constructor(
    @Inject(ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG)
    private readonly environmentConfig: IEnvironmentConfig,

    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID)
    private readonly platformId: string,
  ) {
    this.environmentConfig = {
      ...DEFAULT_CONFIG,
      ...this.environmentConfig,
    }

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.environment = this.getEnvironmentValues<T>();
    }
  }

  protected getEnvironmentValues = <T>(): T => {
    // more code here
  };

}
```

Each project has different interface for its environment values, which is `T` in the above example.

`T` can be provided by extending the above class as such:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxEnvironmentService } from 'src/modules/ngx-environment/src/public-api';

import { IEnvironment } from '../interfaces';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EnvironmentService extends NgxEnvironmentService<IEnvironment> {}
```

`EnvironmentService` is what would get injected into components. This way you can leverage common functionality, but specify types with very little effort.

Hope that helps you out.